# Geviertstrich als Gedankenzeichen?

Tags: typography

[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geviertstrich) sagt zum Geviertstrich (—), dass er im Deutschen kaum noch verwendet wird, da er als zu lange empfunden wird.

Was ist Eure Meinung dazu: Verwendet Ihr den vollen Geviertstrich (—) oder nur den halben (–)?

Gibt es zwischen der Schweiz und den anderen deutschsprachigen Länder Unterschiede dazu?

Comment: Die deutsche Tastatur hat nur den Viertelgeviertstrich, Word macht imho - -> –. Und bis vor 5 Minuten wusste ich nicht mal, dass es eine noch längere Variante gibt: —. Meine Meinung, wir verwenden ausschließlich den halben.

Comment: Eine gute Frage. Als bornierter Ignorant benutze ich für alle Zwecke: Bindestrich, Trennzeichen, Gedankenstrich und Spiegelstrich immer nur das Minus - selbst für Minus. Aber mit professionellem Textsatz habe ich auch nichts zu tun.

Comment: Minus Zeichen ist noch eine andere Geschichte: das Minus auf der Tastatur ist kein echtes minus, eher ein Bindestrich. Das Minus sollte so aussehen, wie das Plus, aber eben ohne den senkrechten Strich...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Christoph Bier beschreibt in [typokurz](https://zvisionwelt.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/typokurz.pdf) mit Beispielen, welche Striche wann wie verwendet werden:

- der **Trennstrich** oder **Divis** ( ‐ ) (Viertelgeviertstrich) für Silbentrennung
- der **Bindestrich** ( ‐ ), ebenfalls das Divis für zusammengesetzte Worte
- der **Gedankentstrich** (Halbgeviertstrich, länger als das Divis) ( – ), steht zwischen Leerzeichen außer in Verbindung mit Satzzeichen
- der **Strecken**- oder **Bis-Strich** ( – ), Halbgeviertstrich ohne Leerzeichen davor und danach
- das **Minuszeichen** ( − ), länger als der Bindestrich, oft dünner als der Gedankenstrich
- der **Auslassungsstrich**, im Text ein Halbgeviertstrich ( – ), in Tabellen ein Geviertstrich ( — )

Der Geviertstrich wird also im Deutschen in der Regel nur als Auslassungstrich in Tabellen verwendet.

*Edit*: Auf [typefacts.com](http://typefacts.com/artikel/grundlagen/bindestrich-gedankenstrich) ist folgendes zu lesen:

> Der längere Geviertstrich (—) kann meist – mit geringeren Abständen –
>   alternativ zum Gedankenstrich benutzt werden. [Indra Kupferschmidt](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/3721205014?ie=UTF8&tag=typefacts-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1638&creative=19454&creativeASIN=3721205014)
>   schreibt ihm klassische literarische Wirkung zu, wohingegen ihn [Robert
>   Bringhurst](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/0881792063?ie=UTF8&tag=typefacts-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1638&creative=19454&creativeASIN=0881792063) als »zu lang für gute Typografie« bezeichnet.

*Edit 2*:
Jan Tschichold schreibt in „[Ausgewählte Aufsätze über Fragen der Gestalt des Buches und der Typographie](http://books.google.de/books?id=BSNmaoqf3aYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Ausgew%C3%A4hlte%20Aufs%C3%A4tze%20%C3%BCber%20Fragen%20der%20Gestalt%20des%20Buches%20und%20der%20Typographie&hl=de&sa=X&ei=FlCVT7TYK8eKhQfOpaSGBA&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)“ auf Seite 154:

> Der Geviertstrich ist nur in einem einzigen Falle anwendbar und
>   notwendig: in tabellarischen Preisaufzählungen.

Answer (score 4):

Der *"Geviertstrich"* ist so lang wie der Schriftkegel (d.h. ein Buchstabe samt seiner Leerräume) und ist das längste Satzzeichen.

Ein Geviertstrich kommt zum Einsatz als

- **Gedankenstrich** für eine **längere Pause** als der Halbgeviertstrich.
- **Auslassungsstrich** in Tabellen und bei Preisangaben für zwei Stellen.
- **Spiegelstrich** als Aufzählungszeichen.

Allerdings benutze ich selbst aus purer Faulheit nur den Bindestrich, den ich schnell mal auf der Tastatur tippen kann. Typographisch richtig, und wenn es um eine Druckvorlagen geht, sollte man mindestens einen Halbgeviertstrich nehmen, der den Geviertstrich in den allermeisten Fällen ersetzen kann.

Comment: Wie ist "Gedankenstrich für eine längere Pause" gemeint? Meines Wissens nach und wie Clemens z. B. Tschichold zitiert wird im Deutschen nur der Halbgeviertstrich benutzt. Hast Du für eine anderweitige Benutzung einen Link?

Answer (score 2):

Ich (Deutschland) benutze ihn als Gedankenstrich — also wie im Englischen, nur mit deutschen Leerräumen drumherum.

Da ich allerdings v.a. englische Bücher lese, bin ich an den langen Strich auch gewöhnt. Ich glaube mich erinnern zu können, dass er mir in englischen Büchern früher mal aufgefallen war. Das spricht dagegen, dass meine Angewohnheit unter Schriftsetzern verbreitet ist.