# Korrekte Schreibweise von Bereichen von Prozentzahlen

Tags: punctuation, numbers

Im Duden steht ja, dass vor dem Prozentzeichen ein Leerschritt gesetzt wird.

Wie verhält es sich jedoch mit dem Prozentzeichen selbst?
Sollte dieses bei Zahlenbereichen bei jeder Zahl angegeben werden? Order reicht (analog zur Aussprache) ein Prozentzeichen für zwei Zahlen?

Und sollte besser ein einfacher Bindestrich, ein doppelter, ein Gedankenstrich oder ein ausgeschriebenes "bis" verwendet werden?

Was ist folglich richtig:

> 5 % - 10 %
>
> 5 % bis 10 %
>
> 5 - 10 %
>
> 5 bis 10 %

Ist euch da irgendeine entsprechende (DIN-)Norm bekannt?

Comment: halbbreites, geschütztes Leerzeichen (\,) und bis-Strich (--).

Comment: Siehe auch [Geviertstrich als Gedankenzeichen?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4266/geviertstrich-als-gedankenzeichen)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eine Norm dazu kenne ich leider nicht. Meine Meinung dazu: Ich würde es vom Kontext abhängig machen. Im Fließtext würde ich sowohl "Prozent" als auch "bis" (als auch die Ziffern) ausschreiben:

> fünf bis zehn Prozent

In tabellarischen Darstellungen würde ich die dritte oder vierte Variante befürworten, da der Gesamtausdruck schnell überblickt werden kann, so dass Wiederholungen überflüssig sind. Selbst bei anderen Werten halte ich es noch für ok, das Prozentzeichen nur einmal zu setzen:

> 0,34783437 bis 43,365423 %

Übrigens würde ich, wenn es das Medium zulässt, kein Minuszeichen, sondern den [Halbgeviertstrich](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbgeviertstrich) einsetzen. Das Minus sieht gerade bei längeren Ziffernfolgen kümmerlich aus:

> 0,34783437 - 43,365423 %

Dagegen der Halbgeviert:

> 0,34783437 – 43,365423 %

Comment: Ja - manchmal übersieht man die naheliegendsten Dinge; das komplette Ausschreiben des Prozentzeichens sowie des Striches ist wohl die beste Variante (dann stellt sich die Frage eines doppelten "Prozent" erst gar nicht). Danke auch für den Tipp mit dem Halbgeviertstrich - wieder was über Typografie gelernt ;-)

Comment: Was Du hier "Minus" nennst, ist keines sondern ein Trennstrich. Das Minus wäre auch länger aber dennoch die falsche Wahl.

Answer (score 5):

Die entsprechende Norm ist die *DIN 5008: Schreib- und Gestaltungsregeln für die Textverarbeitung"*.

Aus [einer Zusammenfassung](http://www.cabeweb.de/html/din5008.htm):

```
Abschläge von 5 - 15 %
```

DIN 5008 [spricht auch explizit](http://sin.uni-magdeburg.de/sin_media/arbeitshilfen/din_5008_676/Der+Mittestrich.pdf) von einem *Gedankenstrich als Zeichen für "bis"*. [Laut Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbgeviertstrich) wäre das dann in der Tat der *Halbgeviertstrich*.

Answer (score 3):

Die Schreibweise als Bereich ist ja wohl anders, als wenn man mit den Zahlen innerhalb einer Formel rechnet. In der Formel gehört die Maßangabe immer an die Zahl und beim Bereich reicht ein Bindestrich: 5 - 15 %
Analog dazu: Temperaturbereich 0 - 40 °C

Ansonsten als Formel: 20 % - 5 % = 15 % 
Analog dazu: 20 kg - 5 kg = 15 kg

Answer (score 2):

Das Prozentzeichen ist letztlich wie ein Zeichen einer Einheit wie z. B. *kg* oder *m/s* zu behandeln. Das hat zwei Konsequenzen:

1. Eine Einheit darf *niemals* von der zugehörigen Zahl getrennt werden (weder durch Weglassen noch durch einen Zeilenumbruch zwischen Zahl und Einheit). Siehe [Wikipedia-ISO 31](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-0#Ausdr.C3.BCcke) oder auch "Thieme, Satz und Bedeutung mathematischer Formeln", wobei meinem Verständnis nach diese Mathe-Satzregeln ebenfalls zur (Standard-)Typografie gehören.
2. Zwischen der Zahl und der Einheit steht *grundsätzlich* ein Spatium, ein halber Leerschritt (in LaTeX: `\,`). Ist ein halber Leerschritt nicht möglich (die Software kennt den halben Leerschritt nicht, z. B. bei Word), verwendet man einen *geschützen* ganzen Leerschritt. Der geschützte Leerschritt verhindert einen Zeilenumbruch zwischen Zahl und Einheit.

Damit ergeben sich die einzig richtigen Lösungen:

```
5 %--10 %  (wobei "--" einen Halbgeviertstrich "–" darstellt)
5 % bis 10 %
```

Kann ein Strich als "bis" gelesen werden, wird im Deutschen ein Gedankenstrich ohne führendes und nachfolgendes Leerzeichen gesetzt. In LaTeX gäbe das:

```
5\,%--10\,%  ("\," = Spatium, "--" = deutscher Gedankenstrich, Halbgeviertstrich)
5\,% bis 10\,%
```

Im Fließtext würde ich immer "bis" schreiben (passt besser zum umgebenden Text), in Aufzählungen, Lebensläufen etc. schreibe ich in der Regel den Gedankenstrich (kürzer).

Diese Regeln sollten in jedem guten Typografie-Buch, wie z. B. "Lesetypografie" (ISBN 978-3-87439-800-8) oder "Detailtypografie" (ISBN 978-3-87439-642-4) nachzulesen sein.