# "Kilometer pro Stunde" vs. "Stundenkilometer"

Tags: etymology, word-choice, noun, terminology

Manchmal unterläuft sogar den Nachrichtensprechern der Lapsus, "Stundenkilometer" statt "Kilometer pro Stunde" zu verwenden.
Von einem seriösen Wissenschaftler, wie zum Beispiel einem Physiker, habe ich "Stundenkilometer" noch nie gehört.

Was ist denn nun im Hochdeutschen richtig?

Und weiß jemand, wann "Stundenkilometer" entstand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die korrekte Bezeichnung der Einheit der Geschwindigkeit ist physikalisch eindeutig definiert:

> Geschwindigkeit = zurückgelegter Weg / dafür benötigte Zeit

Dabei kann der Weg entweder in der Einheit `km` (Kilometer) oder `m` (Meter), die Zeit in `h` (Stunden) oder `s` (Sekunden) angegeben werden. Im täglichen Leben wird das meistens `km/h` sein.

Spricht man im physikalischen Sinn von "Stundenkilometer", so ist das Produkt von Zeit und Kilometer gemeint (`h * km`). Einen Quotienten benennt man physikalisch immer mit pro (z. B. Kilometer pro Stunde), um Verwechslungen mit dem Produkt (`*`) zu vermeiden.

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Stundenkilometer) weist ausdrücklich darauf hin, dass "Stundenkilometer" **nur umgangssprachlich** verwendet wird.

**Schlussfolgerung**:

Im Hochdeutschen ist ausschließlich "Kilometer pro Stunde" richtig.

Siehe auch [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilometer_pro_Stunde).
Siehe auch [Peter Gerwinski](http://www.peter.gerwinski.de/artikel/stundenkilometer.de.html).

Comment: Was, wenn ich Hochdeutsch in der Umgangssprache verwende? Darf ich dann nicht Stundenkilometer sagen? Das ist doch absurd. Jeder versteht, was damit gemeint ist. In einem wissenschaftlichen Text sollte man hingegen mit Sicherheit darauf verzichten.

Comment: @Clemens: Tatsächlich glaube ich, dass --wenn überhaupt -- nur sehr wenige "reines" Hochdeutsch verwenden, mich eingeschlossen. In der Physik ist Geschwindigkeit eindeutig definiert. Warum also einen *ungenauen* Begriff "Stundenkilometer" verwenden, wenn die exakte Einheit "Kilometer pro/durch Stunde" existiert? Sprache sollte dort, wo sie genau sein kann auch genau sein.

Comment: Bei Wikipedia sollte man ebenfalls einen Blick auf die [Diskussionsseite](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskussion:Kilometer_pro_Stunde#Stundenkilometer) werfen, da genau diese Aussage ("Stundenkilometer ist grundsätzlich falsch") dort Kritisiert wird.

Comment: @Lukas: "Stundenkilometer" ist keine physikalische Einheit, da h*km <> km/h. Ob man multipliziert oder dividiert ist ein kleiner, aber feiner und durchaus entscheidender Unterschied ... Ich respektiere durchaus, dass dieser Unterschied einem Sprachwissenschaftler  nicht bewußt ist. Aber mit diesem Wissen -- hier nachlesbar dargelegt -- sollte auch ein Sprachwissenschaftler sehen, dass der eineindeutigen Benennung (wenn es denn schon eine gibt) der Vorzug zu geben ist. Und das ist die physikalische Definition Kilometer pro Stunde ...

Answer (score 14):

#### Geschwindigkeitsangaben in der deutschen Sprache

Die im [SI-Einheitensystem](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI-Einheitensystem) richtige Geschwindigkeitsmessung in [Meter pro Sekunde](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meter_pro_Sekunde) (m/s) ist außerhalb der Fachsprache nicht gebräuchlich. In der Schriftsprache und im gesprochenen Deutsch haben sich andere Angaben durchgesetzt:

#### [Knoten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knoten_%28Einheit%29)

Die wohl älteste noch heute gebräuchliche Geschwindigkeitsangabe stammt aus der Seefahrt. Ein Knoten entspricht dabei einer Seemeile pro Stunde. Auch die  Fluggeschwindigkeit und die Windgeschwindigkeit können in Knoten (kn) angegeben werden.

#### [km/h](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knoten_%28Einheit%29)

Dies ist im geschriebenen Deutsch die am häufigsten verwendete Geschwindigkeitsangabe auf dem Landweg (z.B. Eisenbahn, Automobil, Motorrad), die auch korrekt den SI-Einheiten entspricht. Auch im gesprochenen Deutsch kann man diese Angabe häufig hören: *"Mein Auto fährt mit 160 ka-emm-ha"*. Weniger häufig hört und liest man auch die ausgeschriebene Form *"Kilometer pro / in der Stunde"*.

Obwohl streng genommen nicht korrekt, wird diese Bezeichnung, wie auch die unten aufgeführten Alternativen, häufig mit der Präposition **"mit"** gebildet:

> *"Wir fahren gerade mit 140 Kilometern pro Stunde"* - *"Wenn wir noch pünktlich ankommen wollen, sollten wir mindestens mit 180 km/h fahren"*

#### [Stundenkilometer](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Stundenkilometer&submit_button=Suche&view=1)

Ein sehr gebräuchlicher Begriff ist die Angabe von Kilometern pro Stunde mit dem gut etablierten Begriff *"Stundenkilometer"*. Zwar wird dieser Begriff von den gängigen Wörterbüchern als Umgangssprache klassifiziert, dennoch finden wir diese Angabe auch häufig außerhalb der gesprochenen Sprache und in seriösen, redigierten Tageszeitungen und Zeitschriften (siehe [Kernkorpus und Zitate aus *"Die Zeit"* bei DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Stundenkilometer&submit_button=Suche&view=1)). Dieser Begriff wird etwa doppelt so häufig verwendet wie die ausgeschriebene Abkürzung *"Kilometer pro Stunde"*.

[image]

#### Gar keine Angabe

Vor allem im gesprochenen Deutsch wird gerne auch die Einheit weggeglassen, wenn aus dem Kontext ersichtlich ist, dass es sich nur um eine Geschwindigkeitsangabe handeln kann:

> *"Wir fuhren mit 180 obwohl dort nur 120 erlaubt war."*

Answer (score 7):

Richtig ist, dass nichts gegen die Verwendung von "Kilometer pro Stunde" spricht, und dass diese Formulierung stilistisch einwandfrei ist.

Wie hier bei [Belles Lettres](http://www.belleslettres.eu/blog/stundenkilometer.php) beschrieben ist der Begriff "Stundenkilometer" nicht zwingend als physikalische Einheit zu analysieren. In "Das Auto fährt 240 Stundenkilometer …" ist das ~en in Stunden keine Pluralendung, sondern ein Fugenlaut. Der Blogger argumentiert, dass auch "Reihenhäuser" keine Multiplikation von Reihen und Häusern darstellt, sondern eine Menge von Häusern, die durch das Attribut in einer Reihe zu stehen eingeschränkt wird – ähnlich würden die Kilometer dadurch näher bestimmt, als es sich um solche handelt, die in einer Stunde zurückgelegt werden können.

Hier ist der Begriff bei Meyers: http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/Meyers?lemma=stundenkilometer zu finden, und hier

> stundenkilometer, m., geschwindigkeit, in der zahl der in einer stunde
>   durchmessenen kilometer ausgedrückt: bei einer windgeschwindigkeit von
>   80 stundenkilometern v. Alten handb. f. heer u. fl. (1909) 3, 754. —
>   http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/displayLinkInfo.tcl?sigle=DWB&formid=GS54747

ein Zitat des grimmschen Wörterbuchs. 'Hochdeutsch' beschränkt die Sprache nicht auf fachsprachlichen Gebrauch, etwa auf die Sprache der Physiker oder Ingenieure. Diesen gehören die Begriffe nicht. Theologen, die durchgängig Latein gelernt haben, sagen auch 'der Zölibat', während der Rest der Sprachgemeinschaft 'das Zölibat' sagt – auch da existiert seit langer Zeit beides nebeneinander. Man darf sich hier aber nicht durch Sympathien auf eine Seite ziehen lassen, um als Schiedsrichter den anderen ihren Sprachgebrauch zu verbieten; es funktioniert sowieso nicht.

Clemens Einspruch im [ursprünglichen Streit](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/5836/266), die grundlegende Einheit sei aber Kilometer und wäre nicht in eine Geschwindigkeit überführbar, kann mit einem Beispiel aus der Physik selbst erschüttert werden: Lichtjahre.

[image: Google NGram]

Google NGram weiß zu berichten, dass der Begriff über 100 Jahre alt ist, und zwischen den 20er und 40er Jahren exponentiell an Popularität gewann.

Comment: Du hast meinen Kommentar offenbar missverstanden. Selbstverständlich ist _Lichtjahr_ eine Strecke und keine Zeit mehr, genauso wie _Stundenkilometer_ eine Geschwindigkeit ist und keine Strecke mehr. Das war genau mein Punkt, der gegen BellesLettres Argumentation spricht. „Streit” ist übrigens etwas hochgegriffen, „Diskussion“ trifft es IMHO besser.

Comment: Abgesehen davon: wie will man denn _Stundenkilometer_ (km/h) _nicht_ als physikalische Einheit verstehen? Das wäre, als wollte man _Newton_ (kg*m/s^2) nicht als physikalische Einheit verstehen. Wie das Wort gebildet wurde und was es tatsächlich bedeutet, hat ja nicht direkt miteinander zu tun. (Und nur damit das klar ist: ich bin _für_ die Verwendung von _Stundenkilometer_, jedenfalls in nicht-naturwissenschaftlichen Texten.)

Comment: *Stundenkilometer* ist (natürlich) eine physikalische Einheit für die Geschwindigkeit - Genauso, wie *Fussbalfelder* eine (sehr gängige) Flächeneinheit ist ;)

Answer (score 2):

Der Kontext ist hier äußerst wichtig. Wenn sich zwei Motorradfahrer an der Tankstelle treffen und sich über die Höchstgeschwindigkeit ihrer Fahrzeuge unterhalten, ist "Stundenkilometer" durchaus in Ordnung, obwohl ich vermute, dass man in diesem Gespräch kaum "Stundenkilometer" sondern eher "ka-em-ha" hören wird. Wenn aber ein Astronom die Bahngeschwindigkeit der Erde um die Sonne in einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit in der Einheit "Stundenkilometer" angibt, wird er von seinen Kollegen ganz üble Kritik einstecken müssen.

### **Kilometer pro Stunde**

Das ist sowohl physikalisch als auch hochsprachlich korrekt. Das allgemeine Schema für Geschwindigkeiten lautet `Längeneinheit pro Zeiteinheit`. Daher sind all diese Angaben korrekt:

1. Meter pro Sekunde
2. Kilometer pro Sekunde
3. Parsec pro Jahr
4. Zoll pro Minute
5. Yard pro Woche

Die Beispiele 1 und 2 werden auch Physiker in wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten verwenden, Beispiel 3 könnte man in der Astronomie finden, und 4 und 5 habe ich frei erfunden, aber auch diese beiden sind zumindest sprachlich völlig in Ordnung.

### **geschrieben »km/h«, gesprochen »ka-em-ha«**

Diese Variante, die vom Fragesteller gar nicht zur Diskussion gestellt wurde, scheint mir mit Abstand die häufigste zu sein. Die geschriebene Form ist absolut korrekt, sie ist alltagstauglich und auch in wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten abgebracht (wenn man davon absieht, dass die Einheit "Stunde" keine SI-Einheit ist, woran aber nur Naturwissenschaftler Anstoß nehmen).
Die gesprochene Form »ka-em-ha« ist ein wenig problematisch, weil sie auch als »kmh«, also als »Kilometerstunden« interpretiert werden könnte. In der Praxis ist das aber nicht zu befürchten, weil es meines Wissens keine sinnvolle physikalische Größe gibt, die als Produkt aus Länge und Zeit darzustellen wäre.
Da der Bruchstrich in "km/h" keine eindeutige Entsprechung im gesprochenen Deutsch hat, lässt man ihn beim Aussprechen einfach weg. Eine Fehlinterpretation ist, wie oben ausgeführt, nicht zu erwarten.

### **Stundenkilometer, Kilowattstunden, Newtonmeter**

**Kilowattstunden**
Für Energie gibt es die Einheit Joule (Formelzeichen J) und auch die veraltete Einheit Kalorie (cal). Trotzdem verwenden Energielieferanten auf den Rechnungen die sie uns schicken, die Einheit Kilowattstunden, was abgekürzt »kWh« ergibt (kleines k = Kilo, großes W = Watt, kleines h = Stunde von lateinisch »hora«) (1 kWh = 3,6 MJ [Megajoule] oder 860 kcal [Kilokalorien]). Dabei wird Energie als das Produkt aus Leistung (gemessen in Watt bzw. Kilowatt) mal Zeit (gemessen in Stunden) ausgedrückt. Mit "Kilowattstunden" ist also "Kilowatt mal Stunden" gemeint.

**Newtonmeter**
Wer schon mal an seinem Auto die Reifen gewechselt hat, wird wissen, dass man die Schrauben nicht zu locker anziehen darf, weil sie sich sonst während der Fahrt lösen können, und man darf sie auch nicht zu fest anziehen, weil sonst die Schraube abreißen könnte. Die hier relevante physikalische Größe heißt Drehmoment, und sie wird wie folgt berechnet:

Kraft, mit der man am Schraubenschlüssel zieht MAL Entfernung des Angriffspunktes der Kraft vom Mittelpunkt der Schraube (unter der Voraussetzung, dass die Kraft im rechten Winkel auf den Schraubenschlüssel wirkt)

Die Einheit der Kraft ist das Newton (Formelzeichen N) und die Einheit für Entfernungen ist das Meter (Formelzeichen m), daher hat das Drehmoment die Einheit "Newtonmeter", also Newton mal Meter (abgekürzt Nm).

**andere zusammengesetzte Einheiten**
Die Physik ist voll mit unzähligen zusammengesetzten Einheiten, die Produkte sind (*Impuls: Newtonsekunde; elektrische Ladung: Amperesekunde, elektrische Leistung: Voltampere, usw.*) und auch voller Einheiten, die Quotienten sind (*Geschwindigkeit: Meter pro Sekunde, Wärmekapazität: Joule pro Kelvin, elektrische Feldstärke: Volt pro Meter, usw.*). Dabei gilt durchgehend und einheitlich die Regelung, dass Quotienten durch das Wort "pro" ausgedrückt werden, während bei Produkten die beiden Teile einfach aneinandergefügt werden.

**Stundenkilometer**
Gemäß dieser universellen Regelung ist "Stundenkilometer" also die Bezeichnung für das Produkt aus einer Dauer von einer Stunde und einer Entfernung von einem Kilometer. Nur gibt es keine sinnvolle physikalische Größe, die das Produkt aus Zeit mal Weg ist. Daher ist dieser Ausdruck in einem Kontext, der Seriösität und/oder Wissenschaftlichkeit vermitteln will, zurecht verpönt.

Dem ist aber entgegenzuhalten, dass es auch andere Kontexte gibt. Wegen der Tatsache, dass "Zeit mal Weg" keinen praktischen Sinn ergibt, wird "Stundenkilometer" daher als "Kilometer pro Stunde" interpretiert, und auch von so gut wie jedem genau so verstanden.

### **Lichtjahr, Reihenhaus**

Diese Wörter sind keine Zusammensatzungen aus physikalischen Einheiten und haben in dieser Diskussion daher nichts verloren. Beim "Reihenhaus" ist das offensichtlich, aber auch das "Lichtjahr" enthält mit "Licht" ein Wort, das keine physikalische Einheit (sondern eine physikalische Größe) ist. Der Begriff "Lichtjahr" erhält erst durch eine Definition eine Bedeutung, und diese Definition lautet "Jene Entfernung, die Licht im Vakuum innerhalb eines Jahres zurücklegt". Somit ist das Lichtjahr eine Non-SI-Längeneinheit, wie auch Angström, Fuß, Meile oder Parsec.

Comment: 2 Spitzfindige Anmerkungen: In Deiner Liste würde ein mph vor `Zoll pro Minute` nicht stören. Geschwindigkeiten allgemein könnte man aber allgemeiner fassen als Irgendwas-pro-Minute, etwa der Herzschlag in Herz, die Geschwindigkeit der CPU mit GHz, der Bytes bei DSL, UMTS und LTE in MBit/s, oder Traffic bei GL&U als qpd usw. Die Lichtjahre waren aber nicht als 2 physikalische Einheiten, sondern als 2 sprachliche Einheiten vorgestellt worden, daher klärt diese Aufklärung niemanden auf, sondern ist eine Nebelkerze.

Comment: Dass man „Stundenkilometer“ in einen wissenschaftlichen Text nicht verwendet, ist IMHO unstrittig. Fällt jemanden eine (echte) zusammengesetzte Einheit ein, die ein Fugen-n verwendet? Mir nicht, und ich glaube, dass dessen Anwesenheit in „Stundenkilometer“ seine künstliche Einreihung in die echten zusammengesetzten Einheiten hinfällig macht. Das tatsächliche Produkt aus Stunde und Kilometer wäre meines Erachtens nach „Stundekilometer“ (obwohl ich eher „Kilometerstunde“ sagen würde, das klingt weniger holprig).

Comment: @userunknown: Der Herzschlag ist keine Geschwindigkeit sondern eine Frequenz, ebenso die Taktfrequenz (die ja auch niemand außer dir "Geschwindigkeit" nennt). Frequenzen misst man in der Einheit "pro Sekunde" oder "Hertz" (mit t vor dem z, benannt nach dem deutschen Physiker Heinrich Rudolf Hertz). Da was du mit DSL, UMTS, LTE usw. meinst sind ebenfalls keine Geschwindigkeiten sondern Datenübertragungsraten, die man in bit/s (oder in Vielfachen davon) misst.

Comment: @Clemens: Zu den verbindlichen Regeln für physikalische Einheiten gehört auch, dass bei Zusammensetzungen eine bestimmte Reihenfolge eingehalten werden muss. Dabei gilt: Länge vor Zeit. Also ist "Stundenkilometer" oder "Minutenmeter" (mit Fugen-n), "Jahresmeile" (mit Fugen-s) auch aus diesem Grund falsch. Wenn es diese Größen gäbe müssten sie "Kilometerstunden", "Meterminuten" und "Meilenjahre" (auch mit Fugen-n) heißten.

Comment: Ich meinte tatsächlich verwendete Einheiten und keine erfundenenen... Ich gebe aber zu, dass mein Argument schwach war. Wir reden hier jedenfalls nicht über Physik (da würde ich Dir voll und ganz zustimmen) sondern über deutsche Sprache. Und die wird nicht (nur) von Physikern gemacht sondern im Alltag, in Büchern, Filmen, Zeitungen... und hier ist Stundenkilometer eben schon lange ein gebräuchliches Synonym für km/h. Das wird sich auch nicht ändern, nur weil Du oder ich das gerne so hätten. (weitere Diskussion bitte im Chat, ansonsten halte ich mich ab jetzt raus)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Die Geschwindigkeit mit der das Herz schlägt wird in Hertz (das war mein Fehler) gemessen. Dass man diese Geschwindigkeit "Frequenz" nennt macht das Wort "Geschwindigkeit" nicht falsch, so wie ich das Kreditinstitut, dass ich besuche, und welches die Sparkasse ist, Bank nennen darf. Ich tippe übrigens auch meine Beiträge mit einer Geschwindigkeit von 180 Anschlägen pro Minute. (z.Zt. im Chat)

Answer (score 0):

`Kilometer pro Stunde` (km/h) heißt es richtig, obwohl sich in der Umgangssprache das eigentlich falsche Stundenkilometer verbreitet hat, denn das würde nach der Nomenklatur `Stunde mal Kilometer` bedeuten. Das Produkt aus Zeit und Weg ergibt aber nicht die Geschwindigkeit und ist deswegen wissenschaftlich gesehen falsch.

Es spricht sich aber bequemer und kürzer, und jeder weiß, was gemeint ist. Vermutlich kann man, um den Begriff zu erklären, "Stunden" als nährere Erläuterung zu "Kilometer" betrachten. Also so, wie 5 Seemeilen fünf Meilen sind, die auf dem Meer zurückgelegt werden, sind 5 Stundenkilometer fünf Kilometer, die in einer Stunde zurückgelegt werden. Das ergibt für mich die logischste Erklärung, wie man äquivalent zu bekannten Einheiten vorgegangen ist, um den Begriff zu bilden.